# TypoScript Insert HeaderData before Style Definitions

Tags: css, google-tag-manager, typoscript, typo3-11.x

I need to insert some headerdata before Style Definitions. To be more precise I want to insert my google tag manager script before my style sheets due to the loading order of my font-family.
At the moment I do it like this:

```
page.includeCSS {
file1 = fileadmin/templates/css/bootstrap.css
page.includeCSS.file1.media = all 
file2 = fileadmin/templates/css/style.css
page.includeCSS.file2.media = all 
file3 = fileadmin/templates/fontawesome/css/all.min.css 
page.includeCSS.file3.media = all 
}

page.headerData {            
    10 = TEXT 
    10.value (
       <script data-cookieconsent="ignore">(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
          })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXXXXX');</script>
    )
}
```

According to the Typo3 Documentation the headerdata "By default, gets inserted after all the style definitions." I think that means, that it also can be inserted before. But I don't know how.
I also don't want to put the css in the headerdata because I cannot concatenate and compress them there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it at first position you could modify the `<head>` tag:

```
page.headTag (
<head>
<script data-cookieconsent="ignore">(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
          })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXXXXX');</script>
)
```

---

A cleaner way would be to reorder the header elements with typoscript:

```
config {
    pageRendererTemplateFile = EXT:site_config/Resources/Private/Templates/templateFile.html
}
```

and then copy the file you can find under `typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Private/Templates/PageRenderer.html` to that location and change the order of the markers.
(Yes, it is an old style marker template file)

Now you can reorder `additionalHeaders` in front of any CSS or JS.

Comment: That's a quite nice idea. I didn't think of that. Works great. Thanks very much!

Comment: The cleaner way is even better. Thanks!